# Fetching a weather API fails because it includes hostname (//127.0.0.1:5501) in the URL

Tags: javascript, openweathermap

i,m running my javascript program to fetch weather for a chosen city, but i get a 404 Not found status because the hostname is automatically included in the url. How can i get rid of this.

GET: http://127.0.0.1:5501/api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Johannesburg&appid=14030b6d26486d5c3dcb78f359f1e791

Comment: Most likely you left the protocol (`'https://'`) out of the url string. Please show the relevant code that makes the request

Comment: fetching `api.xxx.xxx` without at least a leading `//` will fetch from the server the file was loaded from since `api.xxx.xxx` does NOT specify a host